# Detect egoistical emotion

Tags: phrases, discourse-analysis, set-phrases

I'm working on sentiment analysis and currently struggling with egoistical emotion detection on a phrase level. So far, I detect the following phrases:

1. "I'm the best"
2. "I'm rich/powerful/beautiful/important/special/clever"
3. "I'm too good for/at"
4. "I know better than someone..."
5. "I'm not an average Joe"

Can anyone help me with the other phrases that come to your mind that can help to recognize egoistical people?

Comment: Egoistic or pretentious? Your sentences describe a pretentious person.

Comment: @amegnunsen I'm looking for egoistic if those are pretentious, could you please give an example of egoistic ones?

Comment: In aggregate - not at the phrase level - just use of the 1st person generally, especially nominative and possessive, is a good signal.

Comment: @lakul for example: I don't care;

Comment: The title says "egoistical", as does the first sentence of the body. But the last sentence says "egotistical". They're different things. Which one are you asking about? The examples fit egotistical (roughly, arrogant) a lot better than egoistical (roughly, selfish).

Comment: @abarnert I meant "egoistical", thanks for noticing. Edited the question.

Comment: If you're sure about that, then your examples don't make any sense, and even your question doesn't make such sense. "Egoistical emotion detection" could only work if there were consistent emotional correlates of egoism, and there aren't. Plus, people who act egoistically don't characteristically _say_ they put their own gratification above all else; they may talk as if they were as altruistic as anyone (or even more so); they just don't act that way. (Except those with a commitment to some philosophical egoist system like Randian Objectivism—but that's easier to detect directly.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there *is* such a thing as "egoistical emotion" that can be detected.

A huge part of the problem here is confusion between "egoistical" and "egotistical". All of your existing examples are looking to detect whether someone things/feels/etc. that she's superior to other people. That's a sign of *egotism*.<sup>1</sup>

Egoism is a tendency to act selfishly, or without considering the needs of others. It has nothing to do with thinking you're superior to other people.

Egoism is a behavioral tendency, not an emotion.

And it doesn't even have any obvious emotions, or emotional surface signs, that it consistently correlates with. So, what would "egoistical emotion detection" even mean?

Even if you drop the "emotion" part, egoism is probably not easily detectable by language use. Egoistical people<sup>2</sup> often tend to talk as if they were as altruistic as anyone else, and just don't act the way they talk.

---

<sub>1. Arguably only a secondary sign even for egotism; as suggested by Adam Bittlingmayer and amegnusen in the comments it might be better to just look for things like excessive use of first person to detect egotism. But that's beside the point, because neither of those has anything to do with egoism.</sub>

<sub>2. Except for those who are egoistical out of commitment to an egoistic ethical philosophy, such as Randian Objectivism. That probably *could* be detected by them openly describing themselves in selfish terms—although it might be easier to just look for Randian jargon…</sub>